# Postfix mail redirecting with sender change

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, postfix-mta

I know there is a great function of Postfix which allows us to forward emails, so, for example, I have a Postfix service running at mydomain.com and I can send important notifications via email to my clients directly from info@mydomain.com. Also, thanks to forwarding functionality, I can RECEIVE letters back to info@mydomain.com and automatically get them forwarded to my full-featured "real" mailbox, for example, my@gmail.com.

It looks great, but there are two things that still need to be solved.

1. If I limit SMTP listener to 127.0.0.1:smtp, I still can send letters from the code, BUT I can not receive answers anymore. Not sure why. So I have to remove the limitation (but this will allow bad guys to use my Postfix as a spamming route point). Is there any possibility to allow email receive and still leaving SMTP limited to the localhost?
2. Postfix's forwarding does not work in the real life. Actually, the forwarded letters look like sent from the stranger's email (stranger@strangehost.com for example) and any "real" mail provider recognizes them as spam, because the SPF record in my domain says "allow to send only from mydomain.com" and stranger's emails does not pass this check.

So my big question is: Is it a way to implement a "redirection" of emails (not forwarding) so sender email will become "info@mydomain.com" and gmail.com (or other "real" mailbox) will not kick them?